# How to write a file then read from it at same time?

Tags: python, file

How to write a file then read it knowing that I have to write it first because file does not exist when,I use the option **'r+'** but I got the error file does not exist.

```
with open(file,'w') as f:
    f.write("")
with open(file,'r') as f:
    out = f.read()
```

Any Solution?

Comment: Why did you tag this question `python-2.7`? Are you really using Python 2.7? The problem does not seem to be specific to this Python version.

Comment: yes I am using python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```py
file = "test.txt"
try:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
except IOError:
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write("")
```

1. If file exists 
   -> The file is read normally by try, and the read result is output.
2. If the file does not exist 
   -> Try reading the file, but if it doesn't, an IOError is raised. 
   -> When an IOError occurs, it writes the file to the filePath immediately

---

Logic to read after writing file

```py
import os.path

file = 'test.txt'

try:
    if not os.path.isfile(file):
        with open(file, 'w') as f:
            f.write('asd')

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
except IOError:
    print('IOError')
```

Comment: Can you explain why this code solves the problem? "try this" sounds like you don't actually know if it works.

Comment: 1. If file exists ->
The file is read normally by try, and the read result is output.

Comment: 2. If the file does not exist -> Try reading the file, but if it doesn't, an IOError is raised.
-> When an IOError occurs, it writes the file to the filePath immediately and returns nothing. -> Eventually res is returned as None, and if None, writes the file.

Comment: It's so easy, there's nothing more to explain.

Comment: If you just edited your answer and included your last two  comments this would already be an improvement.

Comment: this does not resolve my problem, I already know that this is a new file that does not exist , first i have to create it then read it i am asking if i can do that by less code lines

Comment: @NEW_user 2020, I am curious in what situations and why you do this.

Comment: @NEW_user 2020, Added logic in my answer!